# host file in android

Tags: stock-android, file-permissions

I have a rooted device. I would like to protect my hosts file from being deleted, maybe with a password or something like that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is currently stated ([revision 4](/posts/180176/revisions)), the answer is **No**.

Your hosts file is located at `/system/etc/hosts`, in a filesystem of (probably) ext4. Since ext4 uses regular Unix permissions and Android does *not* support ACL, you have no chance to do so.

However, I don't think you really *should* protect it as it's protected by default, because **`/system` is mounted as read-only by default**. As long as you don't grant your root access to malicious apps, no one will delete your hosts file.

Moreover, there are alternative dirty approaches but I don't think they're much helpful so I'm not posting them here.